# Horizontally Scrolling Table

Tags: html, css, mobile, html-table

I currently have a web app with a table of data. The issue is, there is so much data in the table that it becomes squished and unreadable on mobile devices. I've noticed that Wikipedia has exactly what I'm going for: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ivy_League#section_1

I'd like to create a table that horizontally scrolls, so that the headers of each cell stay the same, and that the content inside can remain untouched.

Edit: here's the table I currently have: http://honedge.com/94296358

Hasn't really been touched :P

Comment: I see you're already using jquery.datatable.js, which supports horizontal scrolling if you turn it on. Look at the sScrollX property.

Comment: Ah I didn't realize this existed. Anyways, the table that I linked to isn't generated by the datatables.js. Is it still possible to add this function?

Comment: My experience with the datatable plugin has been it can do everything you can think of, but there's so much that it's easy to miss. For this one, I think you can just call the datatable() function on your table and set a width. Worth a shot.

Comment: Well I already have datatables.js included. Can I just add a `$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable();` inside my header? The data in the table already exists lol

Comment: Yep, pretty much. It'll stick some of it's own stuff on (paging, filtering) etc that you can turn off (bFilter: false, bPaginate: false, etc). Check out this page, and filter by 'features': http://datatables.net/ref

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to wrap your table in a div with the overflow property set to 'auto', resulting in a scrollable area when the real estate to display the full grid is not there.

Answer (score 2):

As per our discussion up above, something like this should help:

```
$("#example").dataTable({
  bFilter: false,
  bPaginate: false,
  sScrollX: "100%"
})
```

Check the full documentation here: 
http://datatables.net/ref

Comment: This works perfectly going from fullsized desktop browser and re-sizing it but loading the page at the smaller mobile resolution throws it out of whack and only displays 2 columns or 1. Same with loading it on my iPhone :/

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use the sScrollX but, for some reason, it wasn't working as expected. I solved the issue by wrapping only the table, including the headers (but not the other datatable components) in a div with width and overflow set:

```
table=$("#example").dataTable();

table.wrap('<div style="overflow: auto; width: ' + 
table.parent().parent().parent().width()*0.95 + 'px"/>');
```

All table features I tested (sorting, search, number of items to show) was still working.